# Pegar dados janela modal PHP

Tags: php, javascript, modal

Ao clicar em unidade é aberto uma tabela dentro do modal que a partir da escolha do usuário insere a linha desejada no input. Porém quando clico em qualquer linha é inserido o valor da tabela toda. Alguém sabe o que devo alterar no javascript ?

```
<div class="container">
                <h2>Modal</h2>
                <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Unidade</button>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control unidade">
                        <!-- Modal -->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">

                                <!-- Modal content-->
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                        <label class="modal-title">UNIDADE</label>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <table id="unidade">
                                            <?php
                                                  include ("conn.php");

                                                        echo "<table border = 2>";
                                                        echo "<tr>";
                                                        echo "<th>Unidade</th>";
                                                        echo "<th>Descrição</th>";
                                                        echo "</tr>";

                                                    $result = "SELECT codigo, descricao FROM cadunid";
                                                    $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result);

                                                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
                                                        echo "<tr>";
                                                        echo "<td value='unidade'>". $row['codigo'] ."</td>";
                                                        echo "<td>". $row['descricao'] ."</td>";
                                                        echo "</tr>";
                                                    }
                                                ?>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <script>
                        $(document).on('click', 'table', function() {
                            var value = $(this).val(unidade).text();
                            $('.close').trigger('click');
                            $('.unidade').val(value);
                        });
                    </script>
```

Comment: Onde está a classe unidade no html? 

Na parte do JS tem uma variavel unidade que não esta definida tbm...

Comment: Esta definida dentro do input

Comment: a variavel unidade ta definida no input? qual o código html do input.
Precisa postar todo o processo, não está dando pra entender prq falta código.

Comment: o código é esse por completo cara, só preciso arrumar o javascript para pegar o valor das colunas codigo e descrição por completo, e pegar somente o valor da linha que eu selecionar,  este é um modal do bootstrap, se não conseguiu ajudar muito obrigado

Comment: Código está errado, tem até tr que não está sendo aberta, mas enfim. 

No loop while define uma classe para a TD que é clicavel. 

exemplo: class="get-text"

Depois no javascript você faz $('.get-text').click(function(){
 var value = $(this).text();
 $('.unidade').val(value);
})

Comment: verifiquei o post e não tem tr errada, mas obrigado pelo aviso. no caso vou ter que criar um input hidden dentro do while para declarar essa class ?

Comment: Você editou o post a 3 minutos. Antes a tr dentro do while estava errada, agora está certa.

Comment: Se não der certo atualiza o código e comenta aqui que venho olhar.

Comment: não deu certo, obrigado vou retirar o post

Comment: Apresentou algum erro ou não se comportou como vc queria?

Comment: simplesmente não recebe nem clique , devo estar errando no laço while mas  desisto

Comment: Usa a resposta que postei, ela funciona. 

Ao clicar em na td com a classe get-value ele pega o valor dela e coloca no input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
                <h2>Modal</h2>
                <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Unidade</button>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control unidade">
                        <!-- Modal -->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">

                                <!-- Modal content-->
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                        <label class="modal-title">UNIDADE</label>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <table id="unidade">
                                            <?php
                                                  include ("conn.php");

                                                        echo "<table border = 2>";
                                                        echo "<tr>";
                                                        echo "<th>Unidade</th>";
                                                        echo "<th>Descrição</th>";
                                                        echo "</tr>";

                                                    $result = "SELECT codigo, descricao FROM cadunid";
                                                    $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result);

                                                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
                                                        echo "<tr>";
                                                        echo "<td class='get-value'>". $row['codigo'] ."</td>";
                                                        echo "<td>". $row['descricao'] ."</td>";
                                                        echo "</tr>";
                                                    }
                                                ?>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>



     <script>
                        $(document).on('click', '.get-value', function() {
                            var value = $(this).text();
                            $('.unidade').val(value);
                        });
                    </script>
```

Comment: agora funcionou, adicionei a linha $('.close').trigger('click') em cima da linha $('unidade').val(value); e deu certo. Só preciso mexer na  <td> agora, para a linha toda ser selecionavel e só pegar o campo codigo